# Is the local byte buffer cleared after the method finishes executing?

Tags: java, android, bytebuffer

Every second I call the following code:

```
public Data getData(byte[] arr){
    //java.nio
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(arr.length);
    buffer.put(arr);
    ByteBuffer f = ByteBuffer.wrap(arr);        
    //using buffer and f. and calculate data        
    buffer.clear();
    f.clear();      

    return data;
}
```

Will there be memory problems? Does my memory clear? Can this code damage my device?

my device android 4.4

Comment: No, and you don't need the `clear()` calls either. Hard to see why you would need to wrap the array in two `ByteBuffers`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using local variables that mean after executing your method GC will clean up the resources used by the method at the right time. So you do not need to worry about memory leak or damage.

> When using java.nio.ByteBuffer, if it allocates a lot of memory, is it
>   possible that the system files will be erased and the device will stop
>   working?

The answer is that it is impossible. OS will never allow simple apps to damage your file system

Comment: Somewhere I saw that ByteBuffer allocates memory outside of local heap. Does this mean that the GC will not be able to clear the allocated memory? Or I misunderstood something?

Comment: GC is written by professionals they know the core of all classes and allocation places of variables. That is why do not worry

Comment: @OlegMay As long as you're not using `sun.misc.Unsafe`, your variables are local-only and correctly closing any IO-Handles you don't need to worry about leakage

Comment: When using java.nio.ByteBuffer, if it allocates a lot of memory, is it possible that the system files will be erased and the device will stop working? Or, is it possible to spoil the memory chip by constantly allocating memory (every second!) Under the bytebuffer? - I ask because One of the customer’s representatives told me this and allegedly because of my application, the device’s chip has deteriorated and the device does not boot ..

Comment: add this buffer = null; f=null; and GC will take care for other staff

Comment: app installed in system/priv-app.